# Is it possible to catch other's process signal in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

The question is simple- is it possible to write the program, that:

- runs a subprogram (note- other *program*, like `/bin/bash`; not a function), and waits until it ends

and

- catches and handles `SIGINT` or `SIGSEGV` signals sent to the subprogram?

Comment: Depends on what exact semantics you need. But [`ptrace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) is one possibility for achieving your stated requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is easy. 
Second is "maybe", depends on what do you want exactly. [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) system call may help. Using ptrace is not what most people want on daily bases, but it may suite you.